# Adding CSS to my html blows up my python code

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to add CSS to the HTML that my python code generates. This line causes an error when I post the HTML:

```
html += '<link rel=\'stylesheet\' href=\'{{ url_for(\'static\', filename=\'css/main.css\') }}\'>'
```

I also tried putting the quotes on the outside, I get the same error:

```
html += "<link rel=\'stylesheet\' href=\'{{ url_for(\'static\', filename=\'css/main.css\') }}\'>"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:
```

if I remove that one line I can PUT to the web page.

This is the code that writes the HTML to the page:

```
def write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title = None):
    info = get_page_info(auth, pageid)
    ver = int(info['version']['number']) + 1
    ancestors = get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid)
    anc = ancestors[-1]
    del anc['_links']
    del anc['_expandable']
    del anc['extensions']
    if title is not None:
        info['title'] = title
    data = {
        'id' : str(pageid),
        'type' : 'page',
        'title' : info['title'],
        'version' : {'number' : ver},
        'ancestors' : [anc],
        'body'  : {
            'storage' :
            {
                'representation' : 'storage',
                'value' : str(html)
            }
        }
    }
    data = json.dumps(data)
    url = '{base}/{pageid}'.format(base = BASE_URL, pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.put(
        url,
        data = data,
        auth = auth,
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    print("Wrote '%s' version %d" % (info['title'], ver))
    print("URL: %s%d" % (VIEW_URL, pageid))
```

I think I am quoting it wrong. I tried a couple different ways, but have yet to get it right. How can I quote this correctly?

Comment: Try using `html += "..."` so you don't have to escape all the single quotes inside the string.  That should make it easier to see the real error.

Comment: `html += """<link rel='stylesheet' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">"""`

Comment: I've tried all of the suggestions in this thread. I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately. This is the exact error that I'm getting: `raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content/138335201`

Comment: I just found out that `url_for()` depends on flask being installed. I will try installing that and see if I can get this to work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
html += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}\">"
```

Escaping single quotes is not required as the string is enclosed in double quotes. The attribute values are enclosed in double quotes.

or, using triple quotes

```
html += """<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">"""
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both your suggestions. I still get this error when I post:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tdunphy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content/138335201`

Comment: It might be due to a different reason. Can you share the code which handles the request?

Comment: Sure! I've just posted the code that writes the page to confluence in the OP.

Comment: Have you tried to post a request to the API using cURL or any other similar tool? It could be that the problem isn't with the html data you're sending, but something else.

Comment: I tried printing out the HTML variable from the code. Think this will help us get to the bottom of it? https://pastebin.com/p1XjQ7Hk

Comment: why not substitue the value returned by `url_for` to the html?  `html += """<link rel="stylesheet" href="{}">""".format(url_for('static', filename='css/main.css'))`

Comment: I just found out that `url_for()` depends on flask being installed. I will try installing that and see if I can get this to work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string interpolation (`{{ url_for...`) then you need to use f-strings: `f'interpolation: {{url_for(whatever)}}'`

Also you can use double-quoted strings and not bother escaping every single quote: `print("Single 'quotes' are fine here")`

In more complex cases you can use multiline stings, they can contain newlines and other quote markers inside them, `''' this 'is' "ok" '''`. There are `'''string'''` and `"""string"""` versions, functionally the same.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both of these (one at a time), and I'm still getting the same error: `html += """ <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"> """
        html += ''' <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"> '''`

Comment: @bluethundr You're still not using format-strings. If you add f before the opening quote: `f""" my sting """` it should work. Right now `{{ url_for...` is just a text, it is not interpreted by python as a code

Comment: ok, I tried putting an 'f' in front of the quotes and I'm still getting the same error. I tried each of these lines: `        html += f""" <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"> """
        html += f''' <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"> '''`

Comment: Wait a second. Are you sure that you meant PUT and not POST request?

Comment: Sorry yes, I'm using PUT in the request. Think I'll do any better with a POST request?

Comment: I just tried a POST request and got the same result.

Comment: @bluethundr well... ok. I'm not really sure why this happens. One idea is that you're putting <link> not in the <head> section, but IDK why this would make the 400 response...

Comment: ok thanks. I can try putting it outside the head section. just shooting from the hip at this point tbh with you! :)

Comment: Interesting. When I try putting the <link> outside of the head and just leave it in the body I get a 405 error: `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url:` . I'm using this line: `html += f"""<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">""`

Comment: I just found out that `url_for()` depends on flask being installed. I will try installing that and see if I can get this to work!